# Recorrer array en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy empezando con React y Javascript y tengo el siguiente problema:

Cree una tabla que la estoy haciendo dinámica por el backend que lo tengo en laravel y tengo un componente tournament en donde quiero mostrar todos los torneos.

Para esto cree un componente TournamentConfig que es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A este lo importo en mi componente tournament donde tengo la tabla y lo paso como config:
primero lo importe como:

```
import { TournamentConfig } from "./TournamentConfig";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de la tabla se lo paso al componente HeaderTable que tiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero esto no me está andando, y no sé si es la forma correcta de exportar un archivo de configuración como en este caso que esta como arrow function, pero me guié por código que veo en internet.

Comment: Como ya sabes el código va como texto por favor

Comment: TournamentConfig es una función que te va a devolver los datos cuando se ejecute, creo que eso está demás, deberias dejarlo como como un array de objetos, no como una función. Por eso cuando haces map de config no te va a reconocer por que config contiene la función y no los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a sólo exportar los datos sin colocarlos dentro de una función

```
export const TournamentConfig = [
  {
    name: 'name',
    property: 'name'
  },
  {
    name: 'city',
    property: 'city'
  }
];
```

Para usarlo tal y como lo tienes tendrías que llamar la función para que te retorne los datos antes de usarlos.

```
<Table config={TournamentConfig()} dataset={data || []} />
```